# Design by contract tools for actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, design-by-contract

Are there tools for AS-3, like iContract for Java,
which can help in Design by Contract(DBC)?

(Drawing inspiration from **The Pragmattic Programmer**).

Answer (score 2):

Adobe provides "Design by Contract Library" as a part of [Cairngorm 3](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/home/Home/)

Cairngorm Libraries section: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/wiki/CairngormLibraries/

Answer (score 1):

try this simple class: http://blog.sebaslab.com/design-by-contract-class/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: true, the fact is that the answer is practically the source code of the library.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is nothing like this until now.